# Не удается подключить jQuery: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: jQuery

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, что значит эта ошибка?

> `Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: jQuery
> Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in http://localhost/ppl/templates/bixa/js/jquery.sweet-menu-1.0.js:
>     jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 1):

это значит что в jquery.sweet-menu-1.0.js прописанный класс jQuery не найден.
Другими словами, перед вызовом данного скрипта, нужно вставлять скрипт, где находится сам jQuery.